# ¿Cómo hacer que mi where ignore el filtro si no lo cumple en PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Tengo mi consulta en donde solicito un código de instituto, su fecha de creación y el estado de pago en el que se encuentra; a estas dos últimas las filtro con un where. Sin embargo me solicitan que igual se pueda filtrar por el código de institución y si este no cumple con las otras 2 condiciones anteriores (está vacío, no hay reportes en esos 2 parámetros) me devuelva entonces toda la consulta con los primeros 2 filtros, en pocas palabras como si ignorara el tercer filtro que es el del instituto.

Aquí está la consulta que estoy manejando

```
select institutioncode as "Institutioncode",
    status as "Status", 
    creationdate as "Creationdate"
from paymentrequest
where status = 'CONDONED' 
    and creationdate between '2022-11-01' and '2023-02-28' 
    and institutioncode in 
        (select institutioncode
        from paymentrequest
        where institutioncode ='RELEASE' or institutioncode is null)
```

y mi resultado

[image: como no cumple con las condiciones me lo regresa vacío y necesito me regrese toda la consulta ignorandoe ntonces el institutioncode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prueba cambiando `AND` por `OR` en la ultima condición

```sql
select institutioncode as "Institutioncode",
    status as "Status", 
    creationdate as "Creationdate"
    from paymentrequest
    where status = 'CONDONED' 
          and creationdate between '2022-11-01' and '2023-02-28' 
          or institutioncode in 
               (select institutioncode
                from paymentrequest
                where institutioncode ='RELEASE')
```

Comment: Si me arroja la lista ya que ese código de instituto viene vació, sin embargo cuando pruebo con uno que cumple los demás filtros, este me sigue arrojando toda la lista :( y debería arrojarme nomas el del código de instituto especifico...

Comment: elimine la ultima condición de "or institutioncode is null" prueba nuevamente y verifica si asi te funciona

Comment: Probando con diferentes códigos de instituto y estatus de pago, me topo con uno que se cumple los filtros anteriores, por lo que solo debería imprimirse los datos de ese instituto, sin embargo me arrojo todos los que se encuentran en esos filtros, sin hacerle caso al de código de instituto que si esta cumpliendo con el filtro